# Visual Studio 2005 crashes on start-up

Tags: visual-studio, crash, intellisense

In my work environment, Visual Studio currently crashes every time I start our main project unless I delete the .suo (solution options) and .ncb (C++ Intellisense symbols) files.

Obviously, I've found a workaround. Is there a more permanent solution than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1?

Answer (score 2):

Try monitoring the Visual Studio process using a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and get more info. It could be because of some weird file access issues.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer wasn't quite correct, but it pointed in the right direction.

There is a hotfix for VS2k5 SP1 described in KB article 947315 that addresses this issue.

Comment: Can you unaccept the current accepted solution and accept this answer?